# How to set IP to Dynamic?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, dynamic-ip

I need help changing my IP to dynamic or confirming that my is IP to dynamic because I may have set it to static when I installed PiVPN.

/etc/network/interfaces is basically empty

Comment: Your looking for `/etc/dhcpd.conf` not the `interfaces` file. [This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921) is a very good explanation.

Comment: This helped, thanks, I just removed a line that made my IP static.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo raspi-config
```

- Select 'Network Options'
- Select 'WiFi'
- Enter SSID
- Enter SSID passphrase

Comment: That will connect you to a wireless network but not change the IP if it already has been statically assigned. Of the static address is not in the same range this would fail.

Answer (score 0):

This command is to confirm you real IP address. If the IP changed in period of time, normally, it is regarded as not static IP.

> curl -s http://ipv4.icanhazip.com

You mention you use a VPN service. If the VPN successfully run up, you are able to use the above command to check the IP address.